# Rails/Rspec: How to specify a specific form when using "fill_in"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, integration-testing, webrat

I have two forms on a page - one for login, one for signup, and both share a field called "user[username]"

When running integration tests in rSpec, how do I specify that I want actions to be run on a specific form?

In solid terms, if I have a form with id 'login' and a form with id 'signup', how do I specify that I want all "fill_in", "click_button" etc commands to be run on the "signup" form?

Comment: This would seem to be a webrat question, rather than Rails or RSpec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need add some scope define by css selector. So you just need to say you want fill user[name] form in form #login_form or #signup_form